# Direct2D different image loadings APIs

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d, wic

I am currently learning Direct2D and I successfully implemented image loading into my test application as described in:

How to Load a Bitmap from a File (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-load-a-direct2d-bitmap-from-a-file)
and
How to Load a Bitmap from a Resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-load-a-bitmap-from-a-resource)

But now I stumbled across the subsection in What's new in Direct2D -> Improved image loading APIs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/what-s-new-in-direct2d-for-windows-8-consumer-preview#improved-image-loading-apis).

Can someone explain to me why these new APIs for loading images are better than the ones used in "How to Load a Bitmap from a File/Resource"? As far as I understand these new functions provide D2D1Image types, which must be converted to D2D1Bitmap before they can be used by the RenderTarget?

Comment: Sprite batching is only useful if you have like hundreds of (usually not not big) images (sprites, particles, etc.) https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32910/what-is-the-technical-definition-of-sprite-batching

Comment: I know how Sprite batching works and when to use it. I asked what the difference between the image loadings APIs is. Maybe it was a bit confusing because the third link points to Sprite batches. But I mean the headline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/what-s-new-in-direct2d-for-windows-8-consumer-preview#improved-image-loading-apis, I will update my question.

Comment: Ok, ID2D1Image are GPU resources. You can now build these from WIC directly. And you can QueryInterface an ID2D1RenderTarget for an ID2D1DeviceContext. Once you have the ID2D1DeviceContext you can call ID2D1DeviceContext::DrawImage with the ID2D1Image instance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-id2d1devicecontext-drawimage(id2d1image_constd2d1_point_2f_constd2d1_rect_f_d2d1_interpolation_mode_d2d1_composite_mode)

Comment: Thanks. But what is the advantage of this? If I want to draw a SpriteBatch I still have to supply a D2D1Bitmap.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't provide implementation details but I suspect this is faster in terms of CPU => GPU performance (this is usually what's costs) as for sprite batch, it won't help. But you can also use the D2D Atlas effect https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/atlas

Comment: So if I want to use SpriteBatch I have to convert the D2D1Image to D2D1Bitmap? Is there a guide for the conversion, because I cannot find it on msdn. And for the atlas effect I can use the D2D1Image directly?

Comment: No, the spritebach must retain an ID2D1Bitmap, don't convert. It just uses a different path to be loaded. An effect can be drawn on a DeviceContext.

Comment: No sorry if I was not clear, I mean if I load the Image with the new API I get D2D1Image and I think I can convert D2D1Image to D2D1Bitmap to use it with e.g. SpriteBatch. Does this make sense or should I use the "old" image loading API if I have to use D2D1Bitmap drawing functions.

Comment: I just saw that D2D1DeviceContext inherits from D2D1RenderTarget, so I think it is better to draw with the DC than with the RT? The ID2D1DeviceContext3 also defines the DrawSpriteBatch functions. So I think it would be a good idea to use the DC for drawing images and if I have to draw a SpriteBatch with the DC I can create a Bitmap from the Image on the DC and pass it to the DC::DrawSpriteBatch function? Sorry for my noob questions.

Comment: Yes, I told you that *"you can QueryInterface an ID2D1RenderTarget for an ID2D1DeviceContext"* they are basically the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! I will read more about DC and RT.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Doc:[Supported Pixel Formats and Alpha Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/supported-pixel-formats-and-alpha-modes)

> When you use the CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap method, you use the
> pixelFormat field of a D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES structure (instead of
> the pixelFormat member of a D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES structure)
> to specify the pixel format of the new render target. It must match
> the pixel format of the WIC bitmap source.
>
> An ID2D1ImageSource is an abstracted provider of pixels. It can be
> instantiated from either WIC (CreateImageSourceFromWic or an
> IDXGISurface (CreateImageSourceFromDxgi).

CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap must match the pixel format of the `WIC bitmap source`.
ID2D1ImageSource can be instantiated from either `WIC` or an `IDXGISurface`. An ID2D1ImageSource that is instantiated from IDXGISurface also supports some YUV pixel formats.

When you create a render target, you must specify its pixel format. For a list of pixel formats and alpha modes supported by each render target, see [Supported Pixel Formats and Alpha Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/supported-pixel-formats-and-alpha-modes).

> When you use the ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateSharedBitmap method, you use
> the pixelFormat field of a D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES structure to specify
> the pixel format of the new render target. It must match the pixel
> format of the ID2D1Bitmap source.

Comment: Fine, but beside the pixel format, what is the main benefit of the D2D1Image compared with D2D1Bitmap. Because most renderTarget drawing functions expect D2D1Bitmap?

Comment: According to the Doc:[Improved image loading APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/what-s-new-in-direct2d-for-windows-8-consumer-preview#improved-image-loading-apis) The Direct2D image source combines the capabilities of these APIs with support for arbitrarily large images, easy integration with printing and effects, and numerous optimizations including YCbCr JPEG and indexed JPEG.